# Find values in table cells with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm using a dynamic table in HTML, but I need to verify the values are not repeated. I'm trying to do it with the value inside the cell rather than the text. These are the values and what I have so far:

```
 var tBody = $("#tablaAplicaciones > TBODY")[0];
 //Add Row.
 var row = tBody.insertRow(-1);

 //Add Name cell.
 var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
 cell.html(nameCountry);
 cell.val(idCountry);

 //Add Country cell.
 cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
 cell.html(nameCompany);
 cell.val(idCompany);


if (($('#tablaApp tr > td:contains(' + countryName + ') + td:contains(' + companyName + ')').length) == 1) {
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Table cells don't have a value, they have `innerText`, `innerHtml`, or as it looks like you are using `Jquery`, `.text()`

Comment: You could give your cells a custom data attribute to represent a value, like `cell.data('val', idCountry)`, then read the "value" using `cell.data('val')`.

Comment: Why not maintain the values in a memory structure with fast lookup, like a `Set`? It will be more efficient than reading out that HTML over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  var idCountry = "9";
  var nameCountry = "United States";
  var idCompany = "9";
  var nameCompany = "Genentech";

  var tBody = $("#tablaAplicaciones > tbody");

  //Create Row
  var row = $("<tr>");

  //Add Country cell to Row
  $("<td>", {
      class: "name-country"
    })
    .data("id", idCountry)
    .html(nameCompany)
    .appendTo(row);

  //Add Company cell to Row
  $("<td>", {
      class: "name-company"
    })
    .data("id", idCompany)
    .html(nameCompany)
    .appendTo(row);

  // Assume vales are not in the table
  var found = -1;

  $("tr", tBody).each(function(i, el) {
    // Test each row, if value is found set test to tue
    if ($(".name-country", el).text().trim() == nameCountry) {
      found = i;
    }
    if ($(".name-company", el).text().trim() == nameCompany) {
      found = i;
    }
  });

  if (found == -1) {
    // If test is false, append the row to table
    row.appendTo(tBody);
    console.log("Row Added", row);
  } else {
    console.log("Values already in Table, row: " + found);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablaAplicaciones">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Company</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-id="1" class="name-country">United States</td>
      <td data-id="1" class="name-company">Apple Inc.</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Using `.each()`, you can iterate over each row and compare the values. A variable can be used as a flag to indicate if the needle was found in the haystack. If not found, you can append the row. Otherwise, do not add the row.

Hope that helps.